# Why does scala immutable Map apply() conform to a functional type?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, implicit-conversion

Why does the following code compile? Is there an implicit conversion that I am missing?

```
object Test {
  def map1[A]: Int => A = Map()
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Map[A, B]` extends `MapLike`, which extends `PartialFunction[A, B]`, which extends `Function1[A, B]`.

A `Map[Int, A]` is a function from `Int => A`. `Map.apply()` returns a new map, and the type annotation just up-casts it to `Int => A`.

Answer (score 1):

In the [documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Map) you can see that `Map[A,B]` extends `A => B` (under linear supertypes). Due to the type annotation of your method the compiler wil infer the map to be of type `Map[Int,A]`.